# External framework in mixed language project ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is it possible to use external objective-c frameworks in a mixed language project?
If yes, then how can I use that in mixed language project?

Comment: You mean Swift & Objective C.

Comment: yes I mean using framework in objective c project containing a swift file and use that framework in swift file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got the answer,
you need to add import statement in a bridging header created for swift file that can have name like [ProjectName]-Swift.h 
then your [ProjectName]-Swift.h file will look like

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

    #import <FrameworkName>       // for framework
    #import "File Name"           // for file
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can work with Both Objective C & Swift. Create project using swift language then create Objective-C classes then project will ask to create 
ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h file ,if you click on Ok.Then it will automatically create file. Then You can directly import Objective Files.